# Поему не появляются border's в рядах таблицы?

Tags: html, css, table

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-spacing: 0px 20px;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan='3'>lorem</th>
    <th>lorem</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>lorem</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>lorem</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>lorem</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существуют две различные модели у таблиц: ( **separate** и **collapse** ).
Они служат для установки поведения границ в ячейках таблицы в CSS.

По-умолчанию используется **separate**:

```
table { 
  border-collapse: separate; 
}
```

В этой модели тег `<tr>` не может иметь границ и будет игнорироваться браузерами.
Решением для данной модели таблицы - это использование стилей для тегов `<td>` и `<th>`, которые будут находиться внутри тега `<tr>`.

```
  <tr>
    <th>lorem</th>
    <td>lorem</td>
  </tr>
```

Так же вы можете установить поведение таблицы в **collapse**:

```
table { 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
```

Это позволит вам стилизовать тег `<tr>` как вам хочется.

Данный вопрос уже поднимался [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040842/add-border-bottom-to-table-row-tr/) на stackoverflow.

Ниже представлен ваш код в исполнении каждой из моделей поведения таблицы:

```css
table, td, th {
border: 2px solid red;
}
#table-separate {
  border-collapse: separate;
}
#table-collapse {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<h3>table-collapse</h3>
 <table id=table-collapse>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan='3'>lorem</th>
    <th>lorem</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>lorem</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>lorem</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<h3>table-separate</h3>
 <table id=table-separate>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan='3'>lorem</th>
    <th>lorem</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>lorem</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>lorem</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: А что, если нужна такого типа таблица? http://prntscr.com/laic63 Я никак не могу задать по-нормальному отступы, если буду использовать collapse, а если буду использовать второй вариант, то никак не могу задать бордеры, как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Отступы текста от границ таблицы, можно задать обычным свойством 'padding', для нужных колонок.
td, th {
    padding: 10px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
   }